# Why is a type guard failing type-check

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typeguards

In a React project I am using a type guard to ensure I am passing down a prop that has the appropriate type. This seems to work because TypeScript is not raising any error in my IDE. But when running type-check as a command, the compiler fails on that prop.

I have a component that is rendering a child component. That child component needs to receive a prop with a custom type, declared in an enum `AuthorizedType`. To ensure that the prop passed is valid, I created a type guard `isAuthorizedType`. If the type is not valid, the component won't render.

Because the child component is not rendered when the type guard is failing, TypeScript is not raising any error in my IDE. But when running type-check as a command, the compiler raises the error:

> TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'AuthorizedType'.

I wonder why is the error not raised in the IDE but raised when running type-checking. I understand that type guards perform a *runtime* check, and I wonder what it means exactly and if that's related.

Here is the code:

```js
// ParentComponent.tsx

export enum AuthorizedType {
  First = 'first',
  Second = 'second',
}

function isAuthorizedType(value: any): value is AuthorizedType {
  return Object.values(AuthorizedType).indexOf(value) !== -1;
}

function ParentComponent({value}: {value: string}) {
  const isValidType = isAuthorizedType(value);

  if (!isValidType) {
    return null;
  }

  return (<ChildComponent value={value} />)
}
```

```js
// ChildComponent.tsx
import {AuthorizedType} from '..';

function ChildComponent({value}: {value: AuthorizedType}) {
  switch(value) {
    case AuthorizedType.First:
      return <div>first</div>
    case AuthorizedType.Second:
      return <div>second</div>
  }
}
```

By moving the type guard into the child component, type-check is not raising any error anymore:

```js
// ChildComponent.tsx
import {AuthorizedType} from '..';

function isAuthorizedType(value: any): value is AuthorizedType {
  return Object.values(AuthorizedType).indexOf(value) !== -1;
}

function ChildComponent({value}: {value: string}) {
  const isValidType = isAuthorizedType(value);

  if (!isValidType) {
    return null;
  }

  switch(value) {
    case AuthorizedType.First:
      return <div>first</div>
    case AuthorizedType.Second:
      return <div>second</div>
  }
}
```

I would like to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through your edits I thought it best to write up another answer entirely. Your program logic doesn't seem flawed to me and after verifying it, so I believe you've found a bug in TypeScript's control flow analysis.

[Here's a playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKV1ym) that works **as expected** on TS versions equal or below `4.3.5` but **not as expected** on versions equal or above `4.4.4`. On the buggy version (>=`4.4.4`), the compiler reckons the return type of `ParentComponent` to be `null`, but actually calling the emitted `ParentComponent()` function returns `"first"`.

I might've of course missed a configuration flag or something that affects how CFA works, or there might've been an intentional change in version 4.4.x, so check if you can find a related bug [in GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues?q=is%3Aissue+enum+type+guard+control+flow+analysis). If not, I think you should [file a report about this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md#4-did-you-find-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

Your `ChildComponent` is marked to expect an `AuthorizedType` as [`props`](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). However in `ParentComponent` you're calling the child with `{ prop: AuthorizedType }` as `props`. `AuthorizedType` extends `string` and that cannot overlap with the type `{ prop: AuthorizedType }` and thus you get a TS2322 error.

The reason it goes away in your situation is when you move the `isAuthorizedType` call into your child component, it's trying to check if the `props` value it receives (i.e. `{ prop: AuthorizedType }`) *is* an `AuthorizedType` (which it cannot be, since `object` does not extend `string`), assigns `false` to `isValidType`, and renders `null`.

So the problem is caused by expecting `AuthorizedType` as `props` in `ChildComponent` when actually you should expect `{ prop: AuthorizedType }`. Of course, you'll probably want to name the property with something more descriptive like "value":

```
function Child(props: { value: AuthorizedType }) {
    switch(prop.value) {
        case AuthorizedType.First:
            return <div>first</div>
        case AuthorizedType.Second:
            return <div>second</div>
    }
}
```

The following format (using [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)) is equivalent to the above one but might prove more ergonomic:

```
interface ChildProps {
    value: AuthorizedType
}
function Child({ value }: ChildProps) {
    switch(value) {
        case AuthorizedType.First:
            return <div>first</div>
        case AuthorizedType.Second:
            return <div>second</div>
    }
}
```

You'll then call the `Child` with e.g. (see [jsx `...` spread attributes](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes)):

```
function ParentComponent(props: ChildProps) {
    return isAuthorizedType(props.value)
        ? <Child {...props} />
        : null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry I made a syntax error when converting my code to a minimal reproducible example. The prop was always either of type string or of my custom type, neither an object. I updated my thread. 

The last example that you are writing is what is raising an error when running a type-check. This is not raising an error in the IDE though. It's this discrepancy I am trying to understand.